# How to pass a value obtained from a function call within a ForMember() into another one using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

On **CreateMap()** I'd like to use the returned value from a function call within a **ForMember()** to avoid having to call the same function twice.

```
CreateMap<source, destination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Variable2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => testFunction(src.Variable1))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Variable3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => testFunction(src.Variable1));
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: Please explain the requirement a bit more. Where exactly you want to use the result from the function call ?

Comment: @Dimitar, Firstly thanks for replay. Well, like I said i'd like to use the result from the first MapFrom into the second (in that example). In other words i'd like to assing the result to a variable and then use it into another ForMember() avoiding having to call the same function several times.

Comment: I think this is not possible. The labdas that are passed to the `ForMember` are not executed at the moment, but rather later on the mapping stage, so you don't have the immediate result of executing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can influence the order in which the properties get mapped via `SetMappingOrder`.

Ensure that eg. property `Variable2` gets mapped via a call to `testFunction` before property `Variable3` gets mapped.
After that, property `Variable3` can be mapped from the value already set in property `Variable2`.

To do so, set the mapping order of `Variable2` to eg. 1 and give the one of `Variable3` a higher value, eg. 2.

The example below shows that the `testFunction` has only run once as `Variable2` and `Variable3` have been given the same `Guid` value.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { 

    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.Variable2, 
            opt => {
                opt.SetMappingOrder(1); // Will be mapped first.
                opt.MapFrom(src => testFunction(src.Variable1));
            })
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.Variable3, 
            opt => {
                opt.SetMappingOrder(2); // Will be mapped second.
                opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => dest.Variable2);
            });
    });

IMapper mapper = new Mapper(config);

var source = new Source {
    Variable1 = "foo"
    };

var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);

Console.WriteLine($"variable2: {destination.Variable2}");
Console.WriteLine($"variable3: {destination.Variable3}");

// variable2: FOO 377dd1f8-ec1e-4f02-87b6-64f0cc47e989
// variable3: FOO 377dd1f8-ec1e-4f02-87b6-64f0cc47e989
```

---

```
public string testFunction(String arg)
{   
    return $"{arg.ToUpper()} {Guid.NewGuid()}";
}
```

---

```
public class Source
{
    public String Variable1 { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public String Variable2 { get; set; }
    public String Variable3 { get; set; }
}
```